# Android scrollview not resizing the way I expected

Tags: android, android-scrollview

I'm using a layout for a configuration panel comprising a LinearLayout (vertical) containing two sub-views: a main subview that's a ScrollView (it has lots of stuff in it - more than fits on the screen, so I'm using the ScrollView to deal with that) and a panel that appears when something in the configuration panel changes (with the usual things: a button to save and a button to revert). The problem is that I can't convince the ScrollView to shrink to allow the "save/revert" panel any space on the screen.

Here's an excerpt of the layout file: [*EDIT: added contents of ScrollView*]

```
<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical">

    <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/scrollView">

            <TextView
                    style="?android:listSeparatorTextViewStyle"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/tweeterLK_options"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15sp"
                    android:id="@+id/textView5"/>

            <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

                <CheckBox
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/fgIntervalPrompt"
                        android:id="@+id/fgEnable"
                        android:checked="true"
                        android:paddingRight="5dp"/>

                <Spinner
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/fgInterval"/>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    >

                <CheckBox android:id="@+id/bgEnable"
                          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                          android:text="@string/bgIntervalPrompt"
                          android:checked="true"
                        />

                <Spinner android:id="@+id/bgInterval"
                         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                         android:prompt="@string/bgIntervalPrompt"/>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

                <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:text="@string/tlkConfig_cacheDepth_prompt"
                        android:id="@+id/textView"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>

                <Spinner
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/cacheDepth"
                        android:prompt="@string/tlkConfig_cacheDepth_prompt"
                        />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

                <CheckBox
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/tlkConfig_preload_avatar"
                        android:id="@+id/preload_avatar"
                        android:checked="true"
                        android:layout_weight="1"/>

                <CheckBox
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/tlkConfig_preload_images"
                        android:id="@+id/preload_images"
                        android:checked="false"
                        android:layout_weight="1"/>
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:visibility="visible">

            <TextView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/account"
                    style="?android:listSeparatorTextViewStyle"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15sp"
                    />

            <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:text="@string/signed_in_as"
                    android:id="@+id/signed_in_as"
                    android:visibility="visible"/>

            <Button android:id="@+id/sign_in"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/sign_in"
                    android:visibility="gone"/>

            <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/sign_out"
                    android:id="@+id/sign_out_button"
                    android:visibility="visible"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/lk_options_header"
                    style="?android:listSeparatorTextViewStyle"
                    android:layout_marginTop="14sp"
                    />

            <CheckBox
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/lkServer_enableLK"
                    android:id="@+id/lkServer_enable"
                    android:checked="false"/>

            <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/lkServer_selection">

                <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:text="@string/lkServer_serverListLabel"
                        android:id="@+id/lkServerLabel"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:layout_marginRight="3dp"/>

                <Spinner android:id="@+id/lkServerSpinner"
                         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                         android:prompt="@string/lkServerSpinnerPrompt"
                         android:longClickable="true"/>
            </LinearLayout>

            <CheckBox
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/lkServer_inUse"
                    android:id="@+id/lkServer_useRecommendation"
                    android:checked="false"/>
        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/settings_changed"
                  android:orientation="horizontal"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="0dip"
                  android:layout_weight="1"
                  android:visibility="gone">
            <Button android:id="@+id/save"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="@string/save_settings"
                />
        <Button android:id="@+id/revert"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="@string/reset_settings"
                />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

When I make the `@id/save` layout visible (using `setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)`) it doesn't cause that ScrollView to resize. Any thoughts on why that is and what I should do about it?

I have 2 options: a) fix the size of the scrollview so that it always leaves room for the panel, or b) get rid of the panel and just pop up a dialog when the back button is pressed. I like the second one better mostly because I already have that working.

Answer (score -1):

There is no content within the scrollview.Please add contents

```
<ScrollView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/scrollView">


//Place your layouts and contents here for things to get scroll


</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Seriously? I did say that there's more stuff than fits on the screen. 

I'll go edit it and put in all the other stuff, but that's not really the issue, is it?